# Best Way To Update Databse String Without Recompiling Code

Tags: vb6

I have an application that references two databases. The issue is, every time the database changes, I have to change the database string in the source code and recompile the exe. Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking I could save the strings to a file and have the application read from the file. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Yes, config files are widely used and a perfectly appropriate method.

Comment: Or `GetSetting\SaveSetting` as a trivial alternative (Registry)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most common way to handle this is with a config file.